# Taylor's theorem Cauchy's remainder question.

Tags: real-analysis

I was studying the rigorous definition of Taylor's theorem and various kinds of remainders' forms when I got stuck at this question.

If $f^{ii}(a)=f^{iii}(a)=f^{iv}(a)=.....=f^{n-1}(a)=0$ but $f^{n}(x)$ is continuous non zero at $x=a$, the we need to prove that $$  \lim_{h \to 0} (\theta _{n -1})=1/n$$

where $$f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+.......+\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{n-1} (x+\theta _{n-1}h)$$ 
I tried to use the Cauchy's remainder form by writing

$$R_n= \frac{h^{n-1}(1-\theta)^{n-1} }{(n-1)!} f^n(a+ \theta h)$$

For the sequence to converge now $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} R_n = 0$$ which seems to be perfectly true because of the $\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ and I use limit of $h$ tending to zero, that just makes the whole expression $0$ at once. How can I reach the final answer?

P.S. Though my book mentions the limit in the question as $h$ tending to zero but I just can't fathom as to how can $\theta$ depend on $h's$ decreasing value.

Comment: Is it possible that this $\lim_{h \to 0} (\theta _n -1)=1/n$ could has some typo? It's not possible the relation you wrote because it would mean that $\theta_n\gt1$, for some values of $h$, aganist the formulation for the remainders you've chosen. For these remainders $\theta_n\in(0,1)$

Comment: I am also sceptical about the relation but certainly there is no typo from my side. I have just written what the question wanted me to prove.

Comment: I've find a very similar result, but for $\theta_{n-1}$. Anyway, your equation is not possible to prove because, by the mean value theorem, $\theta_{n-1}\in(0,1)$

Comment: Do post the proof that you have found out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like to insist, but it seems a missing brace. Anyway, it's true that,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\theta_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Fristly, from the hypothesis with the remainder of order $n-1$:

$$f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+\dfrac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)$$

$\dfrac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)=f(a+h)-f(a)-hf'(a)\tag 1$

And isolating $\theta_{n+1}$ in the mean value theorem applied to the $n-1$ derivative:

$f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)-f^{(n-1)}(a)=\theta_{n-1}hf^{(n)}(\xi)$, with $\xi\in(a,a+\theta_{n-1}h)$. So is,

$f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)=\theta_{n-1}hf^{(n)}(\xi)$

$\theta_{n-1}=\dfrac{f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)}{hf^{(n)}(\xi)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)}{\dfrac{h^{n}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(\xi)}$

Taking the limit:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\theta_{n-1}=(n-1)!\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)}{h^{n}f^{(n)}(\xi)}$$

But $f^{(n)}$ is continuous and $f^{(n)}(a)\ne0$, then $\lim_{h\to0}f^{(n)}(\xi)=f^{(n)}(a)$ and can be taken out from the limit operation.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\theta_{n-1}=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{f^{(n)}(a)}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)} (a+\theta _{n-1}h)}{h^{n}}=$$

$$\overset{(1)}=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{f^{(n)}(a)}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-hf'(a)}{h^{n}}$$

By using the L'Hôpital rule $n-1$ times, and remembering that $f^{(n-1)}(a)=0$:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\theta_{n-1}=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{f^{(n)}(a)}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f^{(n-1)}(a+h)-f^{(n-1)}(a)}{n!h}=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{nf^{(n)}(a)}\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f^{(n-1)}(a+h)-f^{(n-1)}(a)}{h}=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{nf^{(n)}(a)}f^{(n)}(a)=\dfrac{1}{n}$$